# Neo4j: Cypher Query With Variable Length and Condition on Node Labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

### What I'm looking for

With **variable length relationships** (see [here in the neo4j manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-match.html)), it is possible to have a variable number of relationships with a certain label between two nodes.

```
# Cypher
match (g1:Group)-[:sub_group*]->(g2:Group) return g1, g2
```

I'm **looking for the same thing with nodes**, i.e. a way to **query for two nodes with a variable number of nodes in between**, but with a **label condition on the nodes rather than the relationships**:

```
# Looking for something like this in Cypher:
match (g1:Group)-->(:Group*)-->(g2:Group) return g1, g2
```

### Example

I would use this mechanism, for example, to find all (direct or indirect) members of a group within a group structure.

```
# Looking for somthing like this in Cypher:
match (group:Group)-->(:Group*)-->(member:User) return member
```

Take, for example, this structure:

```
group1:Group
   |-------> group2:Group -------> user1:User
   |-------> group3:Group
                  |--------> page1:Page -----> group4:Group -----> user2:User
```

In this example, `user1` is a member of `group1` and `group2`, but `user2` is only member of `group4`, not member of the other groups, because a non-`Group` labeled node is in between.

### Abstraction

A more abstract pattern would be a kind of **repeat operator** `|...|*` in Cypher:

```
# Looking for repeat operator in Cypher:
match (g1:Group)|-[:is_subgroup_of]->(:Group)|*-[:is_member_of]->(member:User) 
return member
```

Does anyone know of such a repeat operator? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Possible Solution

One solution I've found, is to use a condition on the nodes using `where`, but I hope, there is a better (and shorter) soluation out there!

```
# Cypher
match path = (member:User)<-[*]-(g:Group{id:1}) 
where all(node in tail(nodes(path)) where ('Group' in labels(node))) 
return member
```

### Explanation

In the above query, `all(node in tail(nodes(path)) where ('Group' in labels(node)))` is one single where condition, which consists of the following key parts:

- `all`: `ALL(x in coll where pred)`: TRUE if `pred` is TRUE for all values in
  `coll`
- `nodes(path)`: `NODES(path)`: Returns the nodes in `path`
- `tail()`: `TAIL(coll)`: `coll` except first element–––I'm using this, because the first node is a `User`, not a `Group`.

#### Reference

- See [Cypher Cheat Sheet](http://assets.neo4j.org/download/Neo4j_CheatSheet_v3.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
MATCH (:Group {id:1})<-[:IS_SUBGROUP_OF|:IS_MEMBER_OF*]-(u:User)
RETURN DISTINCT u
```

This will:

- find all subtrees of the group with ID 1
- only traverse the relationships IS_GROUP_OF and IS_MEMBER_OF in incoming direction (meaning sub-groups or users that belong to group with ID or one of its sub-groups)
- only return nodes which have a IS_MEMBER_OF relationship to a group in the subtree
- and discard duplicate results (users who belong to more than one of the groups in the tree would otherwise appear multiple times)

I know this relies on relationships types rather than node labels, but IMHO this is a more *graphy* approach.

Let me know if this would work or not.

Comment: Yea, this is my "fallback approach". But I dislike the redundancy in it: I already have told the nodes their type (label): `:User`, `:Group`, et cetera. Now, feeding the same information into the relationship as well (`:is_member_of` for users, `:is_subgroup_of` for groups) feels redundant. --- But, in the end, if it's faster, I will probably do it.

Comment: I don't think there is any redundancy. In my example query, the labels are only indicated for the start and end nodes of the paths, not for the nodes in between. You need to define which paths are of interest. My approach is to do that using relationships types and yours is to do that by filtering the labels of the nodes in between.